# Identify if x columns have positive/negative/different values using values in a newly created column

Tags: r

I am trying to identify whether x number of columns have the same direction for the values in those columns (either positive or negative) or if they have different directions (e.g. one is positive and the other negative).

I am currently using `with` to identify if the values in the columns are `> 0`, `< 0` or have a mix of positive and negative numbers in the rows. This is quite long and not efficient at all so I'm wondering if there is a simpler and more appropriate way of identifying whether columns have positive, negative or a mixture of positive and negative values in the rows.

---

I have tried a long winded way of doing this using the below code. This creates multiple columns which I then paste together to get my final column telling me whether the count1 and count2 columns are both positive, both negative, or different in direction. This only really works for two columns because of the length of the code.

```r
# make a data frame to demonstrate
data <- data.frame(count1 = c(1,-1,1,-1), count2 = c(1,-1,-1,1), count3 = c(1,-1,1,-1), count4 = c(1,-1,-1,1))

# if columns count1 and count2 are both less than 0 place a 1 in the new column, otherwise ""
data$direction_test1 <- with(data, ifelse(count1 < 0 & count2 < 0,
                                          1, ""))
# if columns coun1 and coun2 are both greater than 0 place a 2 in the new column, otherwise ""
data$direction_test2 <- with(data, ifelse(count1 > 0 & count2 > 0,
                                          2, ""))
# if columns count1 and count2 are different in direction (one is greater than 0 and the other less than 0) place a 0 in the new column, otherwise ""
data$direction_test3 <- with(data, ifelse(count1 > 0 & count2 < 0,
                                          0, ""))
data$direction_test4 <- with(data, ifelse(count1 < 0 & count2 > 0,
                                          0, ""))

# paste all of the columns together to make a single column
data$direction_test <- paste0(data$direction_test1, data$direction_test2, data$direction_test3, data$direction_test4)
```

---

My data frame looks like this:

```r
data <- data.frame(count1 = c(1,-1,1,-1), count2 = c(1,-1,-1,1), count3 = c(1,-1,1,-1), count4 = c(1,-1,-1,1))
```

```r
  count1 count2 count3 count4 
1      1      1      1      1        
2     -1     -1     -1     -1        
3      1     -1      1     -1       
4     -1      1     -1      1
```

I want to know if all of the values in each row are all positive, all negative, or if they are a mixture. The new data frame should look like this:

```r
  count1 count2 count3 count4 direction
1      1      1      1      1         1
2     -1     -1     -1     -1         2
3      1     -1      1     -1         0
4     -1      1     -1      1         0
```

Where a `1` in the `direction` column indicates all values in the count columns are positive, a `2` in the `direction` column indicates all values in the count columns are negative, and a `0` in the direction column indicates there are a mixture of positive and negative values in the count columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
data %>%
 mutate(direction = rowSums(sign(.)),
        direction = case_when(direction == 4 ~ 1,
                              direction == -4 ~ 2,
                              TRUE ~ 0))

  count1 count2 count3 count4 direction
1      1      1      1      1         1
2     -1     -1     -1     -1         2
3      1     -1      1     -1         0
4     -1      1     -1      1         0
```

Or:

```
data %>%
 mutate(direction = rowSums(sign(.)),
        direction = case_when(direction == ncol(.) ~ 1,
                              direction == -ncol(.) ~ 2,
                              TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: The latter code works perfectly! I applied it to my real dataset across hundreds of rows and multiple columns and it works really well. The former script seems to not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option:

```
data$direction <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) ifelse(all(sign(data[x,]) == 1), 1, ifelse(all(sign(data[x,]) == -1), 2, 0)))
data

  count1 count2 count3 count4 direction
1      1      1      1      1         1
2     -1     -1     -1     -1         2
3      1     -1      1     -1         0
4     -1      1     -1      1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach,

```
i1 <- rowSums(data > 0)

data$direction <- ifelse(i1 == ncol(data), 1, ifelse(i1 == 0, 2, 0))

#  count1 count2 count3 count4 direction
#1      1      1      1      1         1
#2     -1     -1     -1     -1         2
#3      1     -1      1     -1         0
#4     -1      1     -1      1         0
```